# Build an Undo & Redo by making a 'state snapshot'

Tags: c++, image, design-patterns, undo, undo-redo

I would like to build a Undo&Redo class for a image editor, without building the entire command pattern.

Actually in my code, I'm using the MVC pattern, and so I got a bunch of attributes that are updated every times I launch an action:

```
    class model{
    ...code...

public:
        bool is_Flipped_V = false;
        bool is_Flipped_H = false;
        bool is_Rotated = false;
        bool is_Blurred = false;
        bool is_Sharpened = false;
        bool is_Grayscale = false;
        bool is_Sepia = false;
        bool is_Loaded = false;
        bool is_Saved = false;


        int exposure_Val;
        double contrast_Val;
        int red_Val;
        int green_Val;
        int blue_Val;

        int hue_Val;
        int saturation_Val;
        int luminance_Val;

        int angle_Val;
    }
```

my idea would be to create a list, that every time the Observer is notified, it records the actual state of all the upper attributes.
So that, when I want to 'undo' something, I can just re-update my image, by passing the previous attributes states.

Have someone ever done something like? How Can I save the states of the attributes in a list?
Is there a different but better way to implement that?

Comment: A possible better approach would be to only record changes, not the entire state.

Comment: I would not save the state itself, but rather on every action push two lambda functions to the undo/redo stack that do what you want. It comes with the benefit of not having to worry about what state to save, instead only requiring a list of parameterless function pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way to implement Undo/Redo is to follow the [Memento Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/memento_pattern.htm). It stores every undoable operation and allows to jump to any random point in the history. It's an easy and clean pattern that helps to implement this feature.

The Memento pattern uses three actor classes. `Memento` contains the actual state of an object to be restored. `Originator` creates and stores states in `Memento` objects and the `Caretaker` object is responsible to restore an object's state from a collection of `Memento` objects.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point a naive implementation could be to put all your attributes in one `State` struct and have a `std::stack<State> undo` and `std::stack<State> redo` in your Undo/Redo class. Then when you pop the `undo` stack to undo a `State`, you push the same `State` you popped into the `redo` stack. You do the same thing in reverse when you redo a `State`. You pop the `redo` stack and push the popped `State` back into the `undo` stack.

Also remember to clear the `redo` stack when you push a new change to the `undo` stack.